# How to click on specific element in canvas by its coordinates (using WebDriver)?

Tags: ruby, canvas, selenium, watir, watir-webdriver

I have a canvas element on my page and I want to click on specific (x, y) coordinates in this canvas. I use watir-webdriver:

```
element = browser.driver.find_element(:id, 'canvas')
browser.driver.action.move_to(element).move_by(x, y).click().perform
```

But this code just clicks on the center of the canvas, not the specified (x, y) coordinates. What is wrong with it?

UPD:
So now I use this code:

```
element = browser.driver.find_element(:id, 'canvas')
browser.driver.action.move_to(element, x, y).perform
browser.driver.click.perform
```

But it still clicks on the center of the canvas and not on specified (x, y) coordinates... Any thoughts?

UPD 2: This is only the FIREFOX issue (works well in Chrome)

Comment: I've updated my answer in light of your FF issue. Let me know whether that's it.

Comment: I'm using selenium-webdriver 2.37.0 and Firefox 25.0.1. My OS is Ubuntu 13.04.

Comment: Try with FF 24 [available here](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/organizations/all.html). I tested with FF 25 and found that it does not support native events.

Comment: Yeah! It works now with FF 24. Thanks a lot! Any thoughts about native events not working in 25?

Comment: I believe native event support is provided only for ESR (extended support release) versions of FF. If a version is not ESR then there won't be support for native events for it. FF 25 is not ESR, so no support. You can ask Selenium whether native events are available. Versions up to 2.37 have a bug that make this query unreliable but I've put in a [patch](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=6350&can=1&q=reporter%3Ame&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary) which has been accepted. So the next version should be reliable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Movement

`move_to(element)` moves to the center of the element specified and `move_by` is a relative move. So by the end of these two operations, you have moved to the coordinates `(x of element center + x, y of element center + y)`.

You should use `move_to(element, x, y)`. This will move to the `x, y` coordinates relative to the origin of the element.

Relevant [documentation](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/ActionBuilder.html#move_to-instance_method).

#### Firefox

Are you using a version of Selenium and Firefox for which Selenium supports native events? The combination of Selenium 2.37 with Firefox 24 does. I've had test suite fails just because native events were not available.

Comment: Thanks, Louis. 'move_to' suggestion helps a lot. It really moves the mouse to the specified coordinates. But when I use 'click()' the pointer still moves to the center of the canvas and clicks on it: driver.action.move_to(element, 30, 30).perform
driver.action.click.perform

Comment: How do you determine that the location where Selenium clicks is the center of the canvas?

Comment: Canvas reacts on the mouse movement and clicks and shows them. When I use move_to it shows the correct results. But when I call click() mouse immediately moves to the center. You can see the example here: http://processing.org/examples/follow1.html

Comment: Based on my experience with Selenium, here is what I would do: construct an extremely simple case in jsfiddle or whatever to test that I *can* do what I want to do. If I can do it in the simple case, then either I'm doing something wrong when I want to test the actual application or this application is working in a way that does not lend itself to what I'm trying to do. If I can't do it with the simple case, and if I'm absolutely convinced that I'm using Selenium correctly, I've found a bug in Selenium.

Answer (score 1):

I got Selenium to select an area within the Canvas element using the following method:

```
public void selectCanvasArea(int xCanvas, int yCanvas, int xTarget, int yTarget) {
    action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.id("Canvas")),xCanvas,yCanvas) //(300,300)
            .clickAndHold()
            .moveByOffset(xTarget,yTarget) //(600,150)
            .release()
            .perform();
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Download latest selenium webdriver 2.42.1.Tested and it's working in firefox

Answer (score 0):

```
            Robot robot = new Robot();
            robot.delay(3000);

            robot.mouseMove(x, y);
            robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
            robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
```