# how to click a blank area in a browser

Tags: ruby, watir

I want to click on the blank area of a browser. How do I do this with watir?

For example, go to google, enter some words and then click the white space/blank area so that the search suggestions box goes away.

Comment: How about clicking on an page element that doesn't "do" anything?  For example, go to www.example.org and do something like `browser.div.click`.

Comment: show us the HTML     try doing a right click 'inspect' on the area you want to click on, to find out what element or container is there..  then try clicking on the thing that inspect finds.

Answer (score 1):

Two possible ways to tackle this, one I've successfully done and one I haven't.

First, using watir, something I have not tried is here: [How to click on specific element in canvas by its coordinates (using WebDriver)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20285254/how-to-click-on-specific-element-in-canvas-by-its-coordinates-using-webdriver). I haven't looked into this much but it seems like these two guys have it figured.

The thing I have tried, however, is to use something called Sikuli. Sikuli scripts can be run ontop of an existing watir-designated browser because they are purely image-recognition based. You can trigger the sikuli script to execute from within ruby and implement the canvas (blank area) click that way. Sikuli is crazy simple to use if you use the IDE to generate the macro.

Comment: wow ! this looks complicated for my purposes. I only wanted to click some blank area. thanks though.